# speed up mysql query with multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

I'm wondering if there's a way to speed up a mysql query which is ordered by multiple subqueries.

On a music related site users can like different things like artists, songs, albums etc. These "likes" are all stored in the same table. Now I want to show a list of artists ordered by the number of "likes" by the users friends and all users. I want to show all artists, also those who have no likes at all.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `artists`.*, 

    // friend likes
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM `likes`
     WHERE like_type = 'artist'
     AND like_id = artists.id
     AND user_id IN (1,2,3,4, etc) // ids of friends
     GROUP BY like_id
    ) AS `friend_likes`, 

    // all likes
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM `likes`
     WHERE like_type = 'artist'
     AND like_id = artists.id
     GROUP BY like_id
    ) AS `all_likes`

FROM artists
ORDER BY 
    friend_likes DESC, 
    all_likes DESC, 
    artists.name ASC
```

The query takes ± 1.5 seconds on an artist table with 2000 rows. I'm afraid that this takes longer and longer as the table gets bigger and bigger. I tried using JOINS by can't seem to get this working because the subqueries contain WHERE statements.

Any ideas in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In before others - what do you get when you put EXPLAIN before your SELECT statement?

Comment: Do you have your joined columns from artist table indexed?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `JOIN`s instead of subqueries:

```
SELECT
  artists.*, -- do you really need all this?
  count(user_id) AS all_likes,
  sum(user_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)) AS friend_likes
FROM artists a
LEFT JOIN likes l
  ON l.like_type = 'artist' AND l.like_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY 
  friend_likes DESC, 
  all_likes DESC, 
  artists.name ASC;
```

If this doesn't make the query faster, try adding indices, or consider selecting less fields.

Comment: I am afraid this is going to help in performance. The internal query optimizer has probably already reduced the query as much as it can under the circumstances of his environment.

Comment: @d-live: I can imagine the optimizer has replaced each subquery by a join, but will it also put the two subqueries together?

Comment: Aha yes. I commented on the JOIN syntax vs the Non JOIN syntax. Yes you are right in combining the subqueries togeather +1 for that :)

Comment: @d-live: I added an index on the field likes.like_id and the query runs much faster now, ± 0.03 seconds. Is it oke to add an index to a field when it can refer to different columns in different tables? (album_id, song_id or artist_id).

@Martijn: Thanks for showing me how to do this with a JOIN! Query looks much neater now but strangly runs slower. ± 1.7 seconds without the indexed field and ± 0.06 with the indexed field, against ± 1.5 and ± 0.03

Comment: @smek: just another brain wave; have you made `like_type` an enum?

Comment: @Martijn: yes, like_type is an enum. Your query with the JOIN doens't seem to take the user_id index into account, where as the query with the two subqueries do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break this down a bit to see where the time goes. You're absolutely right that 1.5 sec on 2000 rows won't scale well. I suspect you need to look at indexes and foreign-key relationships. Look at each count/group-by query individually to get them tuned as best you can then recombine.

Answer (score 0):

try rolling up into a query using inline IF() and go through the table/join ONCE

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
  artists.*
  , LikeCounts.AllCount
  , LikeCounts.FriendLikeCount
FROM  
  (SELECT
    like_id
    , count(*) AllCount
    , sum( If( User_id in ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ), 1, 0 ) as FriendLikeCount
  FROM
    friend_likes
  WHERE
    like_type = 'artist'
  GROUP BY 
    like_id ) LikeCounts
JOIN artists ON LikeCounts.like_id = artists.id
ORDER BY
  LikeCounts.FriendLikeCount DESC
  , LikeCounts.AllCount DESC
  , artists.name ASC
```

Comment: IN(1,2,3,4) can be rewritten as BETWEEN 1 AND 4, reducing 4 tests into 2.

Comment: @Johan, yes, but the person posting the question was actually offering a list that could be 1, 8, 12, 38, 53, 2300...  I just posted as simple sample.

Comment: The original question stated 1,2,3, etc. So the between made sense. If the list is truly random, than an inner join on user_id might be more in order.

Comment: @Johan, I agree with a possible inner join... However, editing content of posts by others shouldn't be messed with unless substantive purpose.  Just because you have a different SQL styling of statements should not be done "just because".  The way it was originally entered showed easier the relationship of the first query joined to the next...  Leave other people's styling alone unless its completely unformatted by a user who doesn't get the { } for code formatting.

Comment: The list with user_ids is random. I just stated 1,2,3 as an example. @Johan, your query only returns the artists who have one or more likes, not all artists.

Comment: @DRApp didn't mean to diss, just that the formatting ran of the page and then I got carried away. Agree with the relationship between inner and outer select being clearer before.

Comment: @Johan, appreciate it..  I'll try to cut my 4-space gaps down